# Getting an E_OUTOFMEMORY when accessing an Access database with OLEDB

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, office365, oledb

We have this VB.net code that connects to an MS Access Database and tries to insert a new entry:

```
Dim conn As New OleDbConnection
conn.ConnectionString = "Provider="Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0; Data Source=" & DATABASE_PATH & ";Jet OLEDB:Database Password=pass;"
conn.Open()

Dim SqlString As String = "INSERT INTO tblNotes" &
            " ([NotesNumber" &
            "], [NotesTitle" & 
            "], [HasAdditionalLogic" &
            "], [TypeId]) Values (?,?,?,?)"

Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(SqlString, conn)
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("NotesNumber", 1234)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("NotesTitle", "the title")
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("HasAdditionalLogic", False)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("TypeId", 14)

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() 
conn.close()
```

Nothing too fancy, right?
This code worked fine with Access 2016 installed.

Now with the recent upgrade to Office 365 the line

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

causes this error:

'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0' failed with no error message available, result code: E_OUTOFMEMORY(0x8007000E)

Googling for that error message lead to several ideas like using Integer instead of Long Integer in the database, but that did not help either.

And personally, I doubt that the root cause is a lack of memory because the machine has 32GB RAM installed and is set to 32GB of Virtual Memory. The process itself never uses more than 100MB, Windows Process Explorer tells us that the whole RAM uses about 5GB total. So I just cannot believe we are actually running out of memory here.

Any idea?

**Update:**

Okay, we seem to have found the underlying issue here.

You see this line:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("TypeId", 14)
```

In the Access database, the field "TypeId" has been defined as a Primary Key of Data Type "AutoNumber" and Field Size "Long Integer".

Now, if we write the code like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("TypeId", 14I)
```

it runs without an error, but as soon as we change it to:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("TypeId", 14L)
```

we get the crash.

Let me state again that the code with a `Long` works fine with Access 2016, it crashes with the Access from Office 365.

I may be mistaken, but this seems like a bug in Access.

Of course we can now change all the app code from `Long` to `Integer` (or `UInteger`), but this seems like treating the symptoms instead of the root cause.

Can somebody confirm this? Or tell me why exactly this happens? Using a `Long` seems to be correct to me, using an `Integer` instead seems pretty wrong to me.

Comment: It´s recommended to avoid `AddWithValue` use [Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbparametercollection.add?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) instead where you define the parameter type explicitly.

Comment: You get an `E_OUTOFMEMORY` as soon as the Access database file (including any uncommitted transactions and cached data) exceeds 2GB, the maximum size of an Access database. Are you close to that?

Comment: @Alex B: Thanks for this info, we will think about that for the future. The code you see here is just a little test method anyway.

Comment: @Erik A.: We are nowhere near that limit. The database itself is 6MB in size and the whole app uses  never more than 100MB of RAM. So no, this cannot be the problem. And let me repeat: the same code runs fine on a client with Access 2016. The problem seems to be Access 365.

Answer (score 0):

To anybody who might face the same problem: we "fixed" the issue by installing "Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable"
https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13255
and then using

```
Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0
```

instead of

```
Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0
```

That did the trick.
The hint with `.add` instead of `.addWithValue` did not make any difference.